# How to keep columns when printing a Vuetify app

Tags: vuetify.js

I have a simple Vuetify app that looks like this ([Codepen link](https://codepen.io/PequeX/pen/bGwajja)):

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="8">
          <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
            {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="4">
          <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
            {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

It looks as expected when viewed on the browser and when I print the page as well (from the "Debug mode" in Codepen or running the app locally):

[image]

However, I would like to set `xs` columns to `12` and leave the `8`/`4` ratio only for `sm` and up ([Codepen link](https://codepen.io/PequeX/pen/LYReqXM)):

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="8">
          <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
            {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
          <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
            {{ this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name }}
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

It looks as expected when viewed on the browser, but it does not look correct when I print it (from the "Debug mode" in Codepen or running the app locally):

[image]

Why is that happening and how may I fix it?

### Notes

I know the breakpoint may change when printing. Actually, if I use Puppeteer to print the page:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'http://localhost:8081/#/',
    { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' },
  );
  await page.emulateMediaType('print');
  await page.pdf({ path: 'output.pdf', format: 'A4', printBackground: true});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I get the expected `sm` breakpoint, but the `8`/`4` ratio is not kept.

[image]

Comment: Ur post is very informative to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened [an issue in GitHub](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12884), as [noted by @KaelWD](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12884#issuecomment-755191139) (Vuetify developer):

> I think this should be regarded as browser quirks, if you want a consistent print layout it's probably a good idea to write your own stylesheet with `@media print` instead of relying on px breakpoints.